# JMeter recording scripts

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to using JMeter. I have been trying to use HTTP Proxy server but not able to do it.

My JAVA_HOME is set to : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin

PATH:C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;D:\chromedriver_win32;C:\IEDriverServer_x64_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe;C:\Windows\System32;

Site URL: http://localhost:8080/sowodemo/login/login.htm

I have set the firefox browser with proxy server port: 8181 also I have tried giving 8080 and 8876 etc. nothing works 
As I click on start it throws me this error:

```
2015/04/22 12:04:34 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not open/read key store C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified) 
2015/04/22 12:04:34 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Creating Proxy CA in C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2015/04/22 12:04:35 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException:   >> Illegal option:  -ext
Try keytool -help <<
Command failed, code: 1
'keytool -genkeypair -alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_ DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: Kanchana, C=US" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted} -keypass {redacted} -validity 7 -ext bc:c'
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:170)
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateProxyCA(KeyToolUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1356)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:465)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:507)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:381)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 keytool does not support the `-ext` option. Try with java 7 please.

ref :

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html